# Running a single test method with pytest fails (not found)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to run a specific test method with pytest on Python 3.6 with the following command:

```
pytest sanity_test.py::test_check
```

(as mentioned in pytest [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html))

and it fails with the following error message:

```
ERROR: not found: <rootdir>/tests/automation/sanity/sanity_test.py::test_check
(no name '<rootdir>/tests/automation/sanity/sanity_test.py::test_check' in any of [<DoctestModule 'tests/automation/sanity/sanity_test.py'>, <Module 
'tests/automation/sanity/sanity_test.py'>])
```

when I run the whole test file the tests are running properly with:

```
pytest sanity_test.py
```

When I tried running a specific method in isolated project it works perfectly.

Any reason why pytest can't find specifically my test methods on my project?

The file is very simple and looks like this:

```
def test_check():
    pass
```

Comment: Can you add snippet how you have written files?

Comment: Is there a class inside of `sanity_test.py`?

Comment: The file has a single method:

    `def test_check(): 
        pass`

Comment: also make sure you have `__init__.py` files in the folders underneath `tests/`

Comment: @flazzarini I do have `__init__.py` file under `tests/`

Comment: Are you using `--doctest-modules`? Looks like a `pytest` bug to me atm.

Comment: @MatanBakshi I've created [a new issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3843) in `pytest` repository, you're welcome to contribute to the issue description in case I've forgot something.

Comment: @hoefling actually, I didn't use `--doctest-modules`

Comment: @MatanBakshi do you have a `pytest.ini` or a `setup.cfg` in your project? I deduced the doctest usage from the `DoctestModule` in the error output.

Comment: I correct myself, I did have `--doctest-modules` in my `setup.cfg` and removing it did solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank to [hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling), I recognized that I had `--doctest-modules` option in my `setup.cfg` file. Removing this option fixed the problem. 
[hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling) opened an [issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3843) in `pytest` for that problem.